# Which order are libraries searched for in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: libraries, dynamic-linking

If I have a library that can be found in two directories listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, when resolving libraries at runtime which one is used - the first one or the second one?

Comment: Not "of course". I'm asking the question because I found a situation where it seemed to use the second. Maybe because of your qualifier - what happens if it finds a library that it fails to load? It silently skips it?

Comment: Unfortunately my example is super complicated and involves using a non-system glibc (`patchelf --set-interpreter` and all that). Thanks for the hint about `DT_RPATH`. I *think* it's not that - that would presumably show up in `readelf -d` right? Oh well I guess it is something else - just thought I should check the order wasn't backwards for some weird reason (there are plenty of crazy things like that in computing). Cheers for the help.

Comment: Any chance you have a preloaded library? Even if your example is convoluted, laying out a sample scenario that (fairly faithfully) illustrates your situation would greatly help us help you.